# tinymce table plugin default Unit from px to pt

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In the table plugin of tinymce, width and height etc
I would like to do the default units at points instead of pixels.
I tried to replace "px" part in plugin.js with "pt"
Recalculation done when dragging the table width etc.,
It seemed impossible to simply replace it.

Is there any good plan?

best regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE is changing your input back to `px` because `pt` is typically reserved for fonts only. It's not recommended that you use `pt` for sizing tables - TinyMCE will explicitly prevent you from using anything but either a percentage or `px` value.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I use tinymce to format printed matter on the browser,
I wanted to designate with points so that there is no deviation due to the coordinate specification at the time of printing...